# Regex for "/content/.*/"

Tags: regex

I need to build a regex expression that will find occurrences of /content/*/ in a path.
So for example /content/apples/ or /content/oranges/.

I tried  `String patternString = "\w*content";` which finds only the occurence of /content but leaves the rest. How can I add the second part, being slash + a word  + slash.

Comment: use blackslashes then, `\w*\/content\/.*?\/`

Comment: `/content/[^/]+/` (escape forward slashes if necessary)

Comment: `\w*` should be deleted - it’s not related to this problem. GhostOps : forward slashes are not special in regex so don’t need escaping (some languages *delimit* regex using forward slashes, but that’s a different thing), but your `.*?` is slightly simpler than 404’s `[^/]+`. How about a combination of the two: `/content/.*+/`

Comment: @Bohemian if I enter you expression`/content/.*+/` in https://regex101.com/r/6Fhmlc/1 I do get an error. I used this expression in my code `/\w*content/\w+/`

Comment: @Anuska regex101 requires you to escape slashes, similar to JavaScript, so you’d need to enter `\/content\/.*+\/`. Most languages do *not* use slash fir delimiting regex and so do not require you to escape slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments. I used `/content/\w+/`and found [this link really helfpful.](https://regex101.com/r/6Fhmlc/1)